# How to remove the time from datetime format in particular xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, date, datetime

I need to remove the Time from the date-time format.

My current output:

```
<Members>
 <Member>
  <EmployeeName>Dorothy Yan</EmployeeName>
  <DateofBirth>05-30-2016T00:00:00+05:30</DateofBirth>
 </Member>
 <Member>
  <EmployeeName>Dorothy Yan</EmployeeName>
  <DateofBirth>01-25-2014T00:00:00+05:30</DateofBirth>
 </Member>
</Members>
```

I need to remove the time  from DateofBirth

Correct Output

```
<Members>
 <Member>
  <EmployeeName>Dorothy Yan</EmployeeName>
  <DateofBirth>05-30-2016</DateofBirth>
 </Member>
 <Member>
  <EmployeeName>Dorothy Yan</EmployeeName>
  <DateofBirth>01-25-2014</DateofBirth>
 </Member>
</Members>
```

I'm using c# code in WEB API project. any one help me. I searched in Google but unable to find the solution.

Comment: Show us your C# code.

Comment: The basic trick would be to deserialize it to a C# `DateTime`, extract a C# `Date` from it, and serialize it back. Or you can do it with XSLT and only take a substring.

Comment: @Davio please show me some link or sample code.B'cos i new to c#

Comment: Are you serializing a Property or correcting an existing XML? You say "output" as in "I generated this" but your title says "remove [..] time [..] from [..] xml". Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with a regex (without handling XElement or doing DateTime parsing):

```
String xmlInitialContent =  .... // Content of your initial xml  
Regex rgx = new Regex("T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d+\d\d:\d\d");    
String result = rgx.Replace(xmlInitialContent, String.Empty) ;
```

Comment: This modifies all datetimes, not just the date of birth.

Comment: all datetime in his xml sample are all date of birth !

Comment: @Ksv3n Sorry i miss to mention i'm using WEB API in .net. so in my c# page it's contain RegexStringValidator only .

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code that create the date so we can see what type of Date data you used and how you get the ouput. I will assume you're creating the xml from c# because you tag the question with c#. But you should be able to do it with a pattern.

With tostring like that :

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
String dateFormat = thisDate1.ToString("MM dd yyyy");
```

Look here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in youre case the pattern would be MM-dd-yyyy like the exemple.